# Add a string prefix to each value in a pandas string column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I would like to prepend a string to the start of each value in a said column of a pandas dataframe. I am currently using:

```py
df.ix[(df['col'] != False), 'col'] = 'str' + df[(df['col'] != False), 'col']
```

This seems an inelegant method. Do you know any other way (which maybe also adds the character to rows where that column is 0 or NaN)?

As an example, I would like to turn:

```
    col
1     a
2     0
```

into:

```
       col
1     stra
2     str0
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? please write an explanation on what your code does/wish it did

Comment: I thought what the example code does was very clear to the average pandas user. I have added use case examples for your convenience.

Comment: Your description is somewhat at odds with your code.  What is up with the `!= False` business?  Do you want to add `str` to every value or only some?

Comment: to every value, as shown in my example dataframes.

Comment: your example still a bit unclear, do your want something like `df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)`?

Answer (score 447, accepted):

```
df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
```

Example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a',0]})
>>> df
  col
0   a
1   0
>>> df['col'] = 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
>>> df
    col
0  stra
1  str0
```

Comment: thank you. if of interest, dataframe indexes also support such string manipulations.

Comment: How do I do this if conditions must be met prior to concatenation?

Comment: @tagoma, after 4 years, Yes :  it also support the dataframe indexes.  You can create a new  column and append to the index value as : df['col'] = 'str'+df.index.astype(str)

Comment: "astype(str)" might ruin the encoding if you are trying to save to a file in the end.

Comment: When I try this as well as any other approach I get a SettingWithCopyWarning.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution but I get UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U11')) -> None

Answer (score 32):

As an alternative, you can also use an `apply` combined with `format` (or better with f-strings) which I find slightly more readable if one e.g. also wants to add a suffix or manipulate the element itself:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a', 0]})

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: "{}{}".format('str', x))
```

which also yields the desired output:

```
    col
0  stra
1  str0
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can also use f-strings:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: f"str{x}")
```

yielding the same output.

The f-string version is almost as fast as @RomanPekar's solution (python 3.6.4):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a', 0]*200000})

%timeit df['col'].apply(lambda x: f"str{x}")
117 ms ± 451 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit 'str' + df['col'].astype(str)
112 ms ± 1.04 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Using `format`, however, is indeed far slower:

```
%timeit df['col'].apply(lambda x: "{}{}".format('str', x))
185 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: same result, but way slower ;-)

Comment: @Philipp_Kats: I added some timings, thanks for the suggestion! It seems that f-strings are almost as fast; `format` indeed performs worse. How did you compare?

Comment: oh nice! in my understanding `.apply` is always either as fast or slower than "direct" vectorized operations; even if they are not slower, I prefer to avoid them where possible.

Comment: @Philipp_Kats: I agree, however, in this particular case I find it more readable when I also add a suffix, do something with `x` itself etc., but that's just a matter of taste... :)

Answer (score 23):

You can use `pandas.Series.map` :

```
df['col'].map('str{}'.format)
```

In this example, it will apply the word `str` before all your values.

Answer (score 6):

If you load you table file with `dtype=str`
 
or convert column type to string `df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)` 
then you can use such approach:

```
df['a']= 'col' + df['a'].str[:]
```

This approach allows prepend, append, and subset string of `df`.
Works on Pandas v0.23.4, v0.24.1. Don't know about earlier versions.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution with .loc:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 0]})
df.loc[df.index, 'col'] = 'string' + df['col'].astype(str)
```

This is not as quick as solutions above (>1ms per loop slower) but may be useful in case you need conditional change, like:

```
mask = (df['col'] == 0)
df.loc[mask, 'col'] = 'string' + df['col'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 4):

Contributing to prefixing columns while controlling NaNs for things like human readable values on csv export.

`"_" + df['col1'].replace(np.nan,'').astype(str)`

Example:

```
import sys
import platform
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print("python {}".format(platform.python_version(), sys.executable))
print("pandas {}".format(pd.__version__))
print("numpy {}".format(np.__version__))

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':["1a","1b","1c",np.nan],
    'col2':["2a","2b",np.nan,"2d"], 
    'col3':[31,32,33,34],
    'col4':[np.nan,42,43,np.nan]})

df['col1_prefixed'] = "_" + df['col1'].replace(np.nan,'no value').astype(str)
df['col4_prefixed'] = "_" + df['col4'].replace(np.nan,'no value').astype(str)

print(df)
```

```
python 3.7.3
pandas 1.2.3
numpy 1.18.5
  col1 col2  col3  col4 col1_prefixed col4_prefixed
0   1a   2a    31   NaN           _1a     _no value
1   1b   2b    32  42.0           _1b         _42.0
2   1c  NaN    33  43.0           _1c         _43.0
3  NaN   2d    34   NaN     _no value     _no value
```

(Sorry for the verbosity, I found this Q while working on an unrelated column type issue and this is my reproduction code)

Comment: I find it bothersome that `pd.Series([None]).astype('str')[0] == 'None'`. Similarly with `np.nan`. The string "None" is truthy, yet `None` is not. This solution helps account for that +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `radd()` to element-wise add a string to each value in a column (N.B. make sure to convert the column into a string column using `astype()` if the column contains mixed types). An example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 0]})
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('string').radd('str')
```

which outputs

```
    col
0  stra
1  str0
```

It has two advantages over concatenation via `+`:

1. **Null handling:** If the column contains NaN values, `+` simply returns NaN. For example:

   ```py
   df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', float('nan')]})
   df['col'] = 'str' + df['col']
   ```

   which outputs

   ```
       col
   0  stra
   1   NaN
   ```

   which forces you to handle the NaN later using `fillna()` etc.

   However, with `radd()`, you can directly pass `fill_value=` kwarg to handle the NaN values in one function call. For the above example, we can pass `fill_value=''` to treat NaN values as an empty string, so that when we add the prefix string, we get a column of strings:

   ```py
   df['col'] = df['col'].radd('str', fill_value='')
   ```

   which outputs

   ```
       col
   0  stra
   1   str
   ```

   As a side note, there's a difference between using `astype(str)` and `astype('string')`; one important difference is related to null handling; you can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76055971/19123103).
2. **Method chaining:** If you were adding prefixes to strings in a column as part of a method in a pipeline, it might be important to be able to do it using method chaining. `+` forces you to move out of the pipeline whereas `radd` clearly shows that the prepending prefixes come after a chain of methods. For example, we can do the following:

   ```py
   df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 0]})
   df.reset_index().astype({'col': 'string'}).radd({'index': 0, 'col': 'str'})
   ```

   which outputs

   ```
     index   col
   0     0  stra
   1     1  str0
   ```