# Pandas distinction between str and object types

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy

Numpy seems to make a distinction between `str` and `object` types.  For instance I can do:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.dtype(str)
dtype('S')
>>> np.dtype(object)
dtype('O')
```

Where `dtype('S')` and `dtype('O')` corresponds to `str` and `object` respectively.

However pandas seem to lack that distinction and coerce `str` to `object`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(5)})
>>> df.a.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> df.a.astype(str).dtype
dtype('O')
>>> df.a.astype(object).dtype
dtype('O')
```

Forcing the type to `dtype('S')` does not help either.

```
>>> df.a.astype(np.dtype(str)).dtype
dtype('O')
>>> df.a.astype(np.dtype('S')).dtype
dtype('O')
```

Is there any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: As a very brief explanation that isn't a full answer: If you use a string dtype in `numpy`, it's fundamentally a fixed-width c-like string.  In `pandas`, they're "normal" python strings, thus the object type.

Comment: This might address your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018654/strings-in-a-dataframe-but-dtype-is-object - basically they store object ndarray, not strings in ndarray. However, I do support that they could have be more clear when it comes to distinguishing types - for example having an ability to distinguish 'str' from 'mixed' columns which are also reported as 'O'.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Numpy's string dtypes aren't python strings.

Therefore, `pandas` deliberately uses native python strings, which require an object dtype.

First off, let me demonstrate a bit of what I mean by numpy's strings being different:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.array(['Testing', 'a', 'string'], dtype='|S7')
In [3]: y = np.array(['Testing', 'a', 'string'], dtype=object)
```

Now, 'x' is a `numpy` string dtype (fixed-width, c-like string) and `y` is an array of native python strings.

If we try to go beyond 7 characters, we'll see an immediate difference. The string dtype versions will be truncated:

```
In [4]: x[1] = 'a really really really long'
In [5]: x
Out[5]:
array(['Testing', 'a reall', 'string'],
      dtype='|S7')
```

While the object dtype versions can be arbitrary length:

```
In [6]: y[1] = 'a really really really long'

In [7]: y
Out[7]: array(['Testing', 'a really really really long', 'string'], dtype=object)
```

Next, the `|S` dtype strings can't hold unicode properly, though there is a unicode fixed-length string dtype, as well.  I'll skip an example, for the moment.

Finally, numpy's strings are actually mutable, while Python strings are not.  For example:

```
In [8]: z = x.view(np.uint8)
In [9]: z += 1
In [10]: x
Out[10]:
array(['Uftujoh', 'b!sfbmm', 'tusjoh\x01'],
      dtype='|S7')
```

For all of these reasons, `pandas` chose not to ever allow C-like, fixed-length strings as a datatype.  As you noticed, attempting to coerce a python string into a fixed-with numpy string won't work in `pandas`. Instead, it always uses native python strings, which behave in a more intuitive way for most users.

Comment: Actually, pandas does allow numpy-like fixed-length byte strings, although they are little used, e.g., `pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='S1')`

Comment: @mdurant Pandas will accept that statement as valid, but the dtype will be changed from 'S1' to 'O' (object).

Comment: It used to be possible, maybe no more.

Answer (score 9):

Read here, if you arrived here looking read about the difference between `'string'` and `object` dtypes in pandas. As of pandas 1.5.3, there are two main differences between the two dtypes.

##### 1. Null handling

`object` dtype can store not only strings but also mixed data types, so if you want to cast the values into strings, `astype(str)` is the prescribed method. This however casts all values into strings, even NaNs become literal `'nan'` strings. `string` is a nullable dtype, so casting as `'string'` preserves NaNs as null values.

```py
x = pd.Series(['a', float('nan'), 1], dtype=object)
x.astype(str).tolist()          # ['a', 'nan', '1']
x.astype('string').tolist()     # ['a', <NA>, '1']
```

A consequence of this is that string operations (e.g. counting characters, comparison) that are performed on `object` dtype columns return `numpy.int` or `numpy.bool` etc. whereas the same operations performed on `'string'` dtype return nullable `pd.Int64` or `pd.Boolean` dtypes. In particular, NaN comparisons return False (because NaN is not equal to any value) for comparisons performed on `object` dtypes, while `pd.NA` remains `pd.NA` for comparisons performed on `'string'` dtype.

```py
x = pd.Series(['a', float('nan'), 'b'], dtype=object)
x == 'a'

0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
    
    
y = pd.Series(['a', float('nan'), 'b'], dtype='string')
y == 'a'

0     True
1     <NA>
2    False
dtype: boolean
```

So with `'string'` dtype, null handling is more flexible because you can call `fillna()` etc. to handle null values however you want to.<sup>1</sup>

##### 2. `string` dtype is clearer

If a pandas column is `object` dtype, values in it can be replaced with anything. For example, a string in it can be replaced by an integer and that's OK (e.g. `x` below). It might have unwanted consequences afterwards if you expect each value in it to be strings. `string` dtype does not have that problem because a string can only be replaced by another string (e.g. `y` below).

```py
x = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype=str)
y = pd.Series(['a', 'b'], dtype='string')
x[1] = 3                        # OK
y[1] = 3                        # ValueError
y[1] = '3'                      # OK
```

---

This has the advantage where you can use `select_dtypes()` to select only string columns. In other words, with `object` dtypes, there is no way to identify string columns, but with `'string'` dtypes, there is.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [[1], [2,3], [4,5]]}).astype({'A': 'string'})
df.select_dtypes('string')      # only selects the string column


    A
0   a
1   b
2   c



df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [[1], [2,3], [4,5]]})
df.select_dtypes('object')      # selects the mixed dtype column as well


    A   B
0   a   [1]
1   b   [2, 3]
2   c   [4, 5]
```

##### 3. Memory efficiency

String Dtype `'string'` has storage options (python and pyarrow) and if the strings are short, pyarrow is very efficient. Look at the following example:

```py
lst = np.random.default_rng().integers(1000000, size=1000).astype(str).tolist()

x = pd.Series(lst, dtype=object)
y = pd.Series(lst, dtype='string[pyarrow]')
x.memory_usage(deep=True)       # 63041
y.memory_usage(deep=True)       # 10041
```

As you can see, if the strings are short (at most 6 characters in the example above), pyarrow is consumes over 6 times less memory. However, as the following example shows, if the strings are long, there's barely any difference.

```py
z = x * 1000
w = (y.astype(str) * 1000).astype('string[pyarrow]')
z.memory_usage(deep=True)       # 5970128
w.memory_usage(deep=True)       # 5917128
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Similar intuition already exists for `str.contains`, `str.match` for example.

```py
x = pd.Series(['a', float('nan'), 'b'], dtype=object)
x.str.match('a', na=np.nan)

0     True
1      NaN
2    False
dtype: object
```