# What is dtype('O'), in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

I have a dataframe in pandas and I'm trying to figure out what the types of its values are. I am unsure what the type is of column `'Test'`. However, when I run `myFrame['Test'].dtype`, I get;

```
dtype('O')
```

What does this mean?

Comment: `pandas` freely uses `object` dtype when columns contain mixed values (strings, numbers, nan).

Comment: Related: [distinction between str and object types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34881079/19123103)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

It means:

```
'O'     (Python) objects
```

[Source](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

> The first character specifies the kind of data and the remaining characters specify the number of bytes per item, except for Unicode, where it is interpreted as the number of characters. The item size must correspond to an existing type, or an error will be raised. The supported kinds are
>   to an existing type, or an error will be raised. The supported kinds are:

```
'b'       boolean
'i'       (signed) integer
'u'       unsigned integer
'f'       floating-point
'c'       complex-floating point
'O'       (Python) objects
'S', 'a'  (byte-)string
'U'       Unicode
'V'       raw data (void)
```

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672574/2901002) helps if need check `type`s.

Answer (score 62):

## When you see `dtype('O')` inside dataframe this means Pandas string.

What is `dtype`?

Something that belongs to `pandas` or `numpy`, or both, or something else? If we examine pandas code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'float': [1.0],
                    'int': [1],
                    'datetime': [pd.Timestamp('20180310')],
                    'string': ['foo']})
print(df)
print(df['float'].dtype,df['int'].dtype,df['datetime'].dtype,df['string'].dtype)
df['string'].dtype
```

It will output like this:

```
   float  int   datetime string    
0    1.0    1 2018-03-10    foo
---
float64 int64 datetime64[ns] object
---
dtype('O')
```

You can interpret the last as Pandas `dtype('O')` or Pandas object which is Python type string, and this corresponds to Numpy `string_`, or `unicode_` types.

```
Pandas dtype    Python type     NumPy type          Usage
object          str             string_, unicode_   Text
```

Like Don Quixote is on ass, Pandas is on Numpy and Numpy understand the underlying  architecture of your system and uses the class [`numpy.dtype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype) for that.

Data type object is an instance of `numpy.dtype` class that understand the data type **more precise** including:

- Type of the data (integer, float, Python object, etc.)
- Size of the data (how many bytes is in e.g. the integer)
- Byte order of the data (little-endian or big-endian)
- If the data type is structured, an aggregate of other data types, (e.g., describing an array item consisting of an integer and a float)
- What are the names of the "fields" of the structure
- What is the data-type of each field
- Which part of the memory block each field takes
- If the data type is a sub-array, what is its shape and data type

---

In the context of this question `dtype` belongs to both pands and numpy and in particular `dtype('O')` means we expect the string.

---

Here is some code for testing with explanation:
If we have the dataset as dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Timestamp

data={'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'date': {0: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2018-12-12 00:00:00')}, 'role': {0: 'Support', 1: 'Marketing', 2: 'Business Development', 3: 'Sales', 4: 'Engineering'}, 'num': {0: 123, 1: 234, 2: 345, 3: 456, 4: 567}, 'fnum': {0: 3.14, 1: 2.14, 2: -0.14, 3: 41.3, 4: 3.14}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) #now we have a dataframe

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

The last lines will examine the dataframe and note the output:

```
   id       date                  role  num   fnum
0   1 2018-12-12               Support  123   3.14
1   2 2018-12-12             Marketing  234   2.14
2   3 2018-12-12  Business Development  345  -0.14
3   4 2018-12-12                 Sales  456  41.30
4   5 2018-12-12           Engineering  567   3.14
id               int64
date    datetime64[ns]
role            object
num              int64
fnum           float64
dtype: object
```

All kind of different `dtypes`

```
df.iloc[1,:] = np.nan
df.iloc[2,:] = None
```

But if we try to set `np.nan` or `None` this will not affect the original column dtype. The output will be like this:

```
print(df)
print(df.dtypes)

    id       date         role    num   fnum
0  1.0 2018-12-12      Support  123.0   3.14
1  NaN        NaT          NaN    NaN    NaN
2  NaN        NaT         None    NaN    NaN
3  4.0 2018-12-12        Sales  456.0  41.30
4  5.0 2018-12-12  Engineering  567.0   3.14
id             float64
date    datetime64[ns]
role            object
num            float64
fnum           float64
dtype: object
```

So `np.nan` or `None` will not change the columns `dtype`, unless we set the all column rows to `np.nan` or `None`. In that case column will become `float64` or `object` respectively.

You may try also setting single rows:

```
df.iloc[3,:] = 0 # will convert datetime to object only
df.iloc[4,:] = '' # will convert all columns to object
```

And to note here, if we set string inside a non string column it will become string or object `dtype`.

Answer (score 20):

It means "a python object", i.e. not one of the builtin scalar types supported by numpy.

```
np.array([object()]).dtype
=> dtype('O')
```

Answer (score 12):

'O' stands for *object*.

```
#Loading a csv file as a dataframe
import pandas as pd 
train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
col_name = 'Name of Employee'

#Checking the datatype of column name
train_df[col_name].dtype

#Instead try printing the same thing
print train_df[col_name].dtype
```

The first line returns: `dtype('O')`

The line with the print statement returns the following: `object`

Answer (score 0):

Another situation that you might see "object" dtype is when you try to store a big integer that in64 doesn't hold.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.array([pow(2, 20)]).dtype
Out[2]: dtype('int64')

In [3]: np.array([pow(10, 20)]).dtype
Out[3]: dtype('O')
```