# What is meant by dtype('O') in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset of 4 attributes like this:

```
taxi id     date time   longitude   latitude
0   1   2008-02-02 15:36:08     116.51172   39.92123
1   1   2008-02-02 15:46:08     116.51135   39.93883
2   1   2008-02-02 15:46:08     116.51135   39.93883
3   1   2008-02-02 15:56:08     116.51627   39.91034
4   1   2008-02-02 16:06:08     116.47186   39.91248
```

i want to know there data type so i run this code:

```
type(res)
res['taxi id'].dtype
```

it returns

```
dtype('O')
```

I want to classify data into continuous and discrete attributes...

The 'taxi id ' return dtype (O) so i didn't get it that either attribute is discrete or continuous. 
what does this mean?? is  'taxi id' is discrete ?? or something else

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a dtype of 'O' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561991/what-does-a-dtype-of-o-mean)

Comment: python objects.

Comment: i want to classify data as discrete or continuous...some attributes return float so they are continuous but attribute 'taxi_id' return O dtype... so i dint get it