# Check if values in pandas dataframe column is integer and write it to a list if not

Tags: python, pandas, integer

I have a pandas dataframe with a column which could have integers, float, string etc. I would like to iterate over all the rows and check if each value is integer and if not, I would like to create a list with error values (values that are not integer)

I have tried isnumeric(), but couldnt iterate over each row and write errors to output. I tried using iterrows() but it converts all values to float.

```
ID     Field1
1      1.15
2      2
3      1
4      25
5      and
```

Expected Result:

```
[1.15,"and"]
```

Comment: Could you show what `df['Field1'].tolist()` looks like for this DataFrame please?

Comment: I ask because the solution depends on whether the data is all strings or the column has mixed dtypes.

Comment: all are strings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If "Field1" is a column of strings, use `str.isdigit` (returns True for integers only) and negate:

```
df.loc[~df['Field1'].str.isdigit(), 'Field1'].tolist()
# ['1.15', 'and']
```

Alternatively, if the column contains mixed types, use

```
df.loc[~df['Field1'].astype(str).str.isdigit(), 'Field1'].tolist()
# [1.15, 'and']
```

Comment: Works really well.

Comment: @prosti Thank you. I felt it was worth confirming the dtype of OP's data so we could find them a working solution quickly :)

Comment: But it must be string = dtype('object') for that column since we deal with strings in that column. ;) else I am unaware something else may came in like dtype complex.

Comment: @prosti `object` is a broad sweeping generalisation for anything that isn't scalar. This includes strings as well as mixed types. If they are strings, you can directly find a solution. Otherwise you would need to convert them to string first to have the string methods actually return useful results on them.

Comment: Thanks Guys.. I am getting error - bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: Yes, these mixed types, I found one y-day :) I analyzed recently this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561991/what-is-dtypeo/56189706#56189706

Comment: @prosti That's a good answer but keep in mind that `object` can refer to literally anything that is not numeric or datetime. This also includes objects such as strings, lists, and even dictionaries.

Comment: Yes. Its of data type - Object. How to find integers and then negate it for such mixed type columns?

Comment: @cs95 Will keep your tip. Tnx.