# Change Index Type in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, data-science

I am using Pandas in Python 3,

I have a dataframe whose index is like '20160727', but the datatype is 'object'.

I am trying to convert it into string type.

I tried:

```
data.index.astye(str, copy=False)
```

and `data.index = data.index.map(str)`

But even after these two operations,

I get:

```
data.index.dtype is dtype('O')
```

I want to use sort after converting the index to string. How can I convert the index to string datatype so that I can process it like a string?

Comment: [Read about `pandas` datatypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes), strings are stored as dtype `object`

Comment: `pandas` doesn't do string dtypes.  It's either numeric (integer, float) or object.

Comment: @hpaulj how will i sort then?

Comment: It looks like you have dates, you shouldn't be sorting them using string sorting.  Use `datetime` dtypes and sort using that.

Comment: Can you use `df.sort_index()` ?

Answer (score 3):

In pandas, `object` is type string.

`dtype('O')` means it is a python type `object`. 
You can see more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561991/what-is-dtypeo)

As an example of what you want to achieve:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'Jack', 'Steve', 'Ricky'],'Age':[28,34,29,42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[20160103, 20160102, 20160104, 20160101])
df.index =  pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m%d')
df.sort_index()
```