# Not able to change Dtype 'O' to str in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dtype

there is import from CSV file a big chunk of data, Pandas assigned automatically dtype to colums(138), there is one column I have to compare for extract result.

I tried with `astype()` and `apply()` method for change column without success.

I tried with this below:

```
In [78]: df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']=df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].astype(str,errors='ignore')
         df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].dtype
Out[78]: dtype('O')

In [79]: df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']=df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].astype('str',errors='ignore')
         df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].dtype
Out[79]: dtype('O')


In [49]: df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].dtype
Out[49]: dtype('O')

In [50]: df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']=df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].astype(int,errors='ignore')
         df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].dtype
Out[50]: dtype('O')

In [51]: 
     df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']=df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].astype('int',errors='ignore')
     df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].dtype
Out[51]: dtype('O')
```

It does not display any error but also it does not change dtype in column.  it does not change for integer or string.

Comment: `pandas` doesn't do `numpy` strings - the objects are python strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use pandas 0.24+ is possible convert non numeric to missing values by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and then to integers by [Nullable Integer Data Type](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#) if need convert columns to integers:

```
df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']= pd.to_numeric(df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'],errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

But if want strings, if dtype is `object`, then it means obviously [strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574). So no converting is necessary.

Comment: No I think you should use `to_numeric` and then `astype('Int64')` and obviously specify this is for 0.24+ only.

Comment: I tried to change dtype for string or integer, for comparison I need to convert to string.

Comment: @user3118330 - Then convert to integer is not necessary, because `O` is obviously string, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562101) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672552/pandas-cast-column-to-string-does-not-work/42672574#42672574)

Comment: the result is not what I expect:
``
df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01'].head()
0    00000000
1    00000000
2    00000000
3    00000000
4    00000000
Name: PDP_ADDIPV4_01, dtype: object

df.loc[df['PDP_ADDIPV4_01']!=00000000,'PDP_ADDIPV4_01']
0         00000000
1         00000000
2         00000000
3         00000000
4         00000000
5         00000000
``