# What does DataFrame.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']) actually do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm learning data science with the help of an online course. While learning about filtering specific datatype from a DataFrame object in Pandas, I came across this line of code:

```
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
```

The purpose of the module was to show how to get only numeric datatype. 
I'm not able to figure out what all things or data-types are included in the `object` type.

I tried to understand this from documentation given on Scipy Oficial

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically, it will select all the columns except the columns with data type object.

### References:

- [`pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)
- [Text data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the data type in pandas `DataFrame` columns, you can use the `dtype` attribute. If the output is `dtype('0')`, then it means that the values stored in that specific column are Python objects.

Please have a look at the following thread for further information: [What is dtype('O'), in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561991/what-is-dtypeo-in-pandas)

Answer (score -1):

To include/exclude strings you may use the object dtype, it usually refers to string.