# pandas dtypes doesn't return datatype string or date

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

i am using a CSV file read in by pandas as a dataframe, I want to have a list of all the datatypes per column as output - this is what I have so far - the issue I am encountering is, that for all datatypes that are not floats/integers it just returns dtype('O')

My code looks like this:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filePath)
datatypes = dataframe.dtypes   #here we find out how what the datatype is in a given column
datatypes_list = []
for x in datatypes:
    datatypes_list.append(x)
    
datatypes_list
```

which gives me, for the following csv

```
Position,Experience in Years,Salary,Starting Date
Middle Management,5,5584.10, 2019-02-03
Lower Management,2,3925.52,2016-04-18
Upper Management,1,7174.46,2019-01-02
Middle Management,5,5461.25,2018-02-02
Middle Management,7,7471.43,2017-09-09
Upper Management,10,12021.31,2020-01-01
Lower Management,2,2921.92,2019-08-17
Middle Management,5,5932.94,2017-11-21
Upper Management,7,10192.14,2018-08-18
```

this output:

```
[dtype('O'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('O')]
```

But I would want the output to be something like this:

```
[dtype('string'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('datetime')]
```

and only return dtype('O') if there would be different datatypes in the respective column

Answer (score 0):

For your dtypes array, the first position can be interpreted already as a string dtype as in pandas the 'o' stands for object type which means pandas has read it in as mixed values (i.e not just a single primitive data type like a column of all integers)

See [What is dtype('O'), in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561991/what-is-dtypeo-in-pandas) - tl;dr pandas gets dtype() under the hood from numpy, which requires datatypes to be of fixed width so strings are stored as numpy arrays of pointers, hence objects

as for the date column, you just need to first convert the column to a datetime object

```
dataframe['Starting Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['Starting Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

[pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)