# Pandas Merge Not Working As Expected - Incorrect and Missing Merge Results

Tags: pandas, merge

I have two dataframes which I am attempting to merge:

> df1 - UserInfo

```
Employee ID Country
1           UK
100         USA
31          India
6           UK
45          UK
```

> df2 - refcompanylookup

```
Country Company
UK      UK Company LTD 1
USA     US Company LLC 1
India   India Company PVT 1
```

```
UserInfo['Mapped Company'] = UserInfo.merge(refcompanylookup, how = 'left', left_on = 'Country', right_on = 'Country')['Company']
```

Which is returning:

```
Employee ID Country     Mapped Company
1           UK          US Company LLC 1
100         USA 
31          India   
6           UK  
45          UK
```

I am unclear why this is failing. I've checked the dtypes of both df1 Country and df2 Company:

```
UserInfo['Country'].dtype
refcompanylookup['Country'].dtype
```

Which both come back as:

> dtype('O')

Which from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189706/23008727) I understand means they are both string and is ok.

Comment: You should `map`: `UserInfo['Mapped Company'] = UserInfo['Country'].map(refcompanylookup.set_index('Country')['Mapped Company'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think `df.merge` does not what you think it does. There is no need to assign the output of `merge` to a dataframe column. You may try whether this works:

`pd.merge(UserInfo, refcompanylookup, how="left", on="Country")`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, you are trying to make a similar approach as Vlookup in Excel, but it doesn't work with merge as you used. you can try this instead:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'left', on = 'Country')
```

Comment: Is there a way to only return one column from df2?

Comment: You can use this approach instead of merge if you like:

    mapping = dict(df2[['Country', 'Company']].values)
    df1['Mapped Company'] = df1.Country.map(mapping)

this should give you same result as merge.