# Changing datatype in pandas does not change df.info()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe where when doing

```
mydf.info()
```

all the datatypes are non-null object

Then I do:

```
mydf['CCI'] = mydf['CCI'].astype(str)
```

Afterwards

```
mydf.info()
```

shows exactly the same result as before trying to change the data type. 
Why is it that this line of code does not change the type of data of the DF?

Comment: What does your dataframe consist of and what are your expected results? It will definitely help to include an example.

Comment: it should work. ran on a sample test on my end and dtype changed from float to object.

Comment: Strings are seen as `object` when describled by `pandas.info` method.

Comment: ```mydf.info()``` will have label *Data columns* that gives details about the individual columns. For str data type, the column will be showed as type 'object'. If you are seeing the exact same result, it is possible that your column has string data initially too.

Comment: clear and restart the kernel, then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is a difference between string type in numpy and pandas. Numpy has numpy.str however pandas chooses to be closer to python hence the type `O`.

This answers it very clearly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884078/4551984

Comment: @cowflu: "Strings are seen as object when describled by pandas.info method. " I did not know that. That means when df.info() you will never see "string" or "str"

Comment: Indeed, that's my understanding too.