force a column of all NaNs to be seen as a string
I have two dataframes that I need to merge with an automated process with the corresponding details:

They are read as CSV and there is a corresponding type inference of the dtypes.
Most of the time, the on columns are inferred as strings (object) and so merge works correctly.
Sometimes, my automated process only generates NaN for one of the join columns, causing it to be inferred (in my mind incorrectly) as float64. This then causes an error from trying to merge a string and float64 column together.
My desired result is that NaN gets merged to NaN even if one of the two dataframes only contains NaN in the column.

What I think needs to happen is to tell Pandas that even if a certain column only contains NaN, it should still be considered an object column because if it DID contain non-NaN values, they would be strings. This would allow my automated merge to proceed.
However none of the possible commands I have found seem to do this correctly, for example astype(str) will convert NaN to "nan". I would like to specify the datatype when creating the dataframe, but for some reason you can only specify one dtype in the DataFrame constructor.
Here are some commands that reproduce the issue. What this shows is that when the joined dataframe contains both string and NaN (b_df), types are inferred such that the merge can correctly proceed on both string and NaN values. However when the joined dataframe contains only NaN (c_df), merge cannot proceed because of the incorrect type inference.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [['a', '1.2', np.NaN], ['b', '70', 'abc'], [np.NaN, '5', 'def']]
>>> b = [[np.NaN, 12],['a',13]]
>>> c = [[np.NaN, 12]]
>>> a_df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["one","two","three"])
>>> b_df = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=["four","five"])
>>> c_df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["four","five"])
>>> a_df.dtypes
one      object
two      object
three    object
dtype: object
>>> b_df.dtypes
four    object
five     int64
dtype: object
>>> c_df.dtypes
four    float64
five      int64
dtype: object
>>> result1 = a_df.merge(b_df, how="left", left_on=["one"], right_on=["four"])
>>> result1
   one  two three four  five
0    a  1.2   NaN    a  13.0
1    b   70   abc  NaN   NaN
2  NaN    5   def  NaN  12.0
>>> result2 = a_df.merge(c_df, how="left", left_on=["one"], right_on=["four"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/stephendewey/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 9843, in merge
    return merge(
  File "/Users/stephendewey/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 142, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
  File "/Users/stephendewey/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 735, in __init__
    self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
  File "/Users/stephendewey/.pyenv/versions/3.10.13/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py", line 1387, in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

I want to use merge because it seems to work very well for all of my cases except extremely rare situations where I only get NaN in a string column.

Well, looks like you'll need a_df.merge(c_df.astype({'four': object}), ...), no?

ooooh, I guess what I was missing is that object is like str but can contain NaN? I had tried using astype but with str

This answer seems to confirm that (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76055971/783314), although it sort of adds to my confusion as well because it makes me wonder if str is different from 'string' which are both different from object. Guess I'll need to dig into this more.
