# Add new column to pandas data frame based on string + value from another column in the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a data frame using the code below:

```
bins = [['0', '50'], ['0', '100'], ['0', '150'], ['0', '200'], ['0', '250'], ['0', '300'], ['0', '350'], ['0', '400']]
bins = pd.DataFrame(bins, columns = ['start', 'end'])
bins['range'] = bins[['start', 'end']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
bins.start = pd.to_numeric(bins.start)
bins.end = pd.to_numeric(bins.end)
```

data frame looks like this:

```
   start  end    range
0      0   50     0-50
1     50  100   50-100
2    100  150  100-150
3    150  200  150-200
4    200  250  200-250
5    250  300  250-300
6    300  350  300-350
7    350  400  350-400
```

I am trying to add a new column named 'axis' that will include the string 'up to' and then the value from 'end' column, e.g. row 1 'axis' column will show 'up to 50' and row 2 will show 'up to 100'

What is the best way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20027386/15239951)

Comment: @Corralien - Sorry,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
df['axis'] = 'up to ' + df['end'].astype(str)
```