# How to add a character at the end of a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a '%' symbol to the end of number in a column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'value': [2.5, 3.6, 4.2]
})
```

Desired output:

```
 name| value |
  A  | 2.5 % |
  B  | 3.6 % |
  C  | 4.2 % |
```

Attempt:
(I was thinking on a Regex function or maybe Lambda)

```
df[["name", "value"]]=df[["value"]].astype(str).replace(r"(\d{2})", r"\1%", regex=True)
```

Comment: Use `df['value'].map('{} %'.format)`  . Ref link- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20025882/add-a-string-prefix-to-each-value-in-a-string-column-using-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df["value_pct"] = df["value"].astype(str) + " %"
```

The above should give you a dataframe like this:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
  name  value value_pct
0    A    2.5     2.5 %
1    B    3.6     3.6 %
2    C    4.2     4.2 %
```

If you really want to overwrite `value`, then use this:

```py
df["value"] = df["value"].astype(str) + " %"
```

That said, are you sure you want to convert the column to string like this?  Because then you won't be able to perform any mathematical operations.  If you just want to print this out, you shouldn't alter the dataframe.  Maybe  write a custom print function:

```py
def df_print(df):
    _df = df.copy()
    _df["value_pct"] = df["value"].astype(str) + " %"
    print(_df[["name", "value_pct"]].to_string())
```